# How to call dynamically an array by concatenate a string with a number in Dart

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, dynamic, concatenation

say I have Some List inside a List.

```dart
List<List> rules = [
    [],
    [],
    [],
];
```

Beside, I have 3 list.

They will have some widgets inside, base on another process

```dart
List<TextSpan> arrayRule1 = [];
List<TextSpan> arrayRule2 = [];
List<TextSpan> arrayRule3 = [];
```

Say i want to loop through rules, and loop on each array in it.

How can i can make a dynamic call by concatenate the index of the loop with a string, to use the actual existing array ?

```dart
      int indice = 0;

      for (List rule in rules) {
        indice++
        for (String statement in rule) {
          if (statement == "vrai")
            arrayRule+indice.add(// code... ) // Throw an error
          else if (statement == "faux" || statement == "fausse")
            arrayRule+indice.add(// code... ) // Throw an error
          else
            arrayRule+indice.add(// code... ) // Throw an error
        }
      }
```

I do know how to do this in Javascript, but in Dart, I'm lost
I don't want to make a `If...else` statement just to select my previous `arrayRule1` `arrayRule2` `arrayRule3` based on the `indice` variable.

Any idea would be welcome, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection is not easy in dart, look for dart:mirrors package but I think it does not work in flutter. You have to find another way of doing it.

What you can do it create a map like this

```
List<TextSpan> arrayRule1 = [];
List<TextSpan> arrayRule2 = [];
List<TextSpan> arrayRule3 = [];

Map<int, List<TextSpan>> arrayRuleMap = {
    1: arrayRule1,
    2: arrayRule2,
    3: arrayRule3,
};
```

then instead of

```
arrayRule+indice.add(// code... ) // Throw an error
```

You can use

```
arryaRuleMap[indice].add(// code... ) // Throw an error
```

### Edit

For more simplification you can directly initialise array in map instead of creating 3 variables.

```
Map<int, List<TextSpan>> arrayRuleMap = {
    1: [],
    2: [],
    3: [],
};
```

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much !
I don't use so often map in other languages... seems it changed with this language. Appreciate the help.